# What is this children's/young adult book with an abandoned house and a scarab beetle?

Tags: identification-request

This is a young adult/children's book read some time around 2004, in English. Unfortunately no recollection of the cover. Remembered details are:

- a boy is on vacation, or perhaps has moved, in a hot, dusty place
- there is abandoned house
- the boy befriends another child (could also have been an old man with a youthful spirit)
- time jumps to when the house was not abandoned
- a scene with an inexplicable wind inside the house
- a scarab beetle was important, in some way
- I think the book ended with a scarab beetle scuttling in the sand.

Which book is this?

Comment: Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange! What language did you read this book in? Where did you read it? Can you remember anything about the cover? See the [identification-request wiki](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) in case anything else jogs your memory. Every detail helps.

Comment: Seriously, who's voting to close identification-request questions? The poster clearly states that they're looking to find a book they read before and lists enough details that it's plausible only a single book matches. **This isn't a recommendation request, it's an identification request**